# Output of a git command read through shell script is adding special characters when passed again to another git command

Tags: bash, git, shell, git-bash

I have a requirement to delete branches in git repository of a developer who recently left the organization. So I used git for-each-ref to list all the branches then used grep to filter results by developer name (test_developer in the following script). I used shell read and extracted branch into a variable mybr and used git push origin --delete to delete the branch. Please find the code snippet below:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(align:1,left)%(color:yellow)%(authorname)%(end) %(color:reset)%(refname:strip=3)' --sort=authorname refs/remotes | grep test_developer | while read line;do mystr=(${line}); mybr=${mystr[1]}; git push origin --delete "$mybr"; done
```

Issue is am getting output as "fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in :?[mbugfix/CRIP-2475". Here bugfix/CRIP-2475 is the branch name. And I wonder what are those extra characters :?[m that got appended before the branch name.

If I do echo $mybr before git delete I get the value properly printed as "bugfix/CRIP-2475". And if I pass this value manually to git delete, it is working fine. But when it is being passed as a variable, am getting the above error. I suspect there are some special characters being prepended, may be a ctrlM character or something that echo is not printing to the screen.

Is there anyway to remove those extra characters?

Comment: Root cause for this problem is usage of colors. Please look at Phd's solution for the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can remove by using [Bash sub-string replacement](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

`${str/#find/replace}` for replace pre-fix characters

`${str/%find/replace}` for replace post-fix characters

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(align:1,left)%(color:yellow)%(authorname)%(end) %(color:reset)%(refname:strip=3)' --sort=authorname refs/remotes | grep test_developer | while read line;do mystr=(${line}); mybr=${mystr[1]}; git push origin --delete "${mybr/#?[m/}"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

These "magical" symbols are, of course, [colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). You shoudn' use colors in pipes:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(align:1,left)%(authorname)%(end) %(refname:strip=3)' --sort=authorname refs/remotes | …
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. You have solved the root cause for this problem.